# Why in the program "Prolog for eight puzzle" user slago uses the command: reverse([State|States], Path). I can't undestand why he uses this command

Tags: prolog

What is the meaning of this command in Prolog's commanf line? What does time and what does time(ids)?
?- time(ids)

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are typically off-topic here by reason of being too broad. This one is narrower in terms of the _amount_ of code provided being tiny, but doesn't provide enough context to be answerable without outside resources, which is itself grounds to be considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prolog lists are singly linked lists and it's more convenient and more performant to prepend things on the front instead of append them on the end. A common technique is to build a list backwards, then reverse it. Slago is doing that.

The search starts with the Start state in the list, prepends intermediate states, and finishes when `goal(State)` holds and the state at the front of the list is the solved puzzle.

Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67645940/

Comment: Original code Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67645940/